Join v_GS_Installed_Software with v_configurationitems or v_UpdateInfo in SQL
I'm working with the v_GS_Installed_Software table to check the installed software on various machines. I want to join this table with v_configurationitems or v_UpdateInfo to access additional columns like IsLatest, IsExpired, IsSuperseded, and others.
The challenge I'm facing is that while the v_configurationitems and v_UpdateInfo tables contain the CI_ID column, the v_GS_Installed_Software table only has a ResourceID column.
I thought of using the v_UpdateComplianceStatus table to join on CI_ID and then use ResourceID from that table to join with v_GS_Installed_Software. However, this approach doesn't work as expected.
Is there a straightforward way to achieve this join, or is there an alternative method to access the desired columns?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

I don't really undestand what you are trying to do here. v_GS_Installed_Software is a list of software installed on a client acquired through asset intelligence. It is not directly related to any SCCM info. This means all manually installed software is there which can not be joined in any form to IsLatest etc which is Information the Server has about specific updates. I am not even sure if updates are part of Installed_Software at all (we do not have it active) but even if so you could never join on a CI_ID which does not exist as info the client OS knows about
